# OneSignal: onNotificationProcessing not called after some time

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I've successfully implemented OneSignal device-to-device push notifications, but after few hours it stopped working on all 3 devices. Instead of onNotificationProcessing call in logcat appearing following output:

```
11-29 15:51:35.348 16383-16383/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
11-29 15:51:35.348 3672-5620/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.APP.ID (has extras) } U=0: not found
11-29 15:51:35.353 16383-16383/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

In Application class `onCreate`

```
    OneSignal.startInit(ctx).init()
    OneSignal.idsAvailable { osId, gcmId ->
        saveToFirebase(osId)
    }
```

In manifest

```
    <service
        android:name=".BackEnd.PushProcessor"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I'm using OneSignal Android Native SDK v3 and write in Kotlin lang, ProGuard is enabled with obfuscation disabled

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have 2 different Google Project numbers in your app. The Google Registration Id (AKA pushToken) from the older project number will be invalided after a short time if this is the case.

Comment: double checked. I use Firebase, API key and sender id copied straight from Firebase console